# Moving players on chance on a soccer field in R plot

Tags: r, plot, sampling, markov-chains

### Background:

I'm trying to come up with a coding scheme such that any of my 14 players (separately; ***each player is shown as numbered circles below***) on the center thick line of my soccer field independently **moves to left by `.1` (in x-axis value unit)** if the result of `outcome = sample(x = c(1, 2), size = 1)`  is `1` and if the result of `outcome = sample(x = c(1, 2), size = 1)` is `2`, the player **moves to right by `.1` (in x-axis value unit).**

Thus, the goal is that each player can independently move to the left or right based on the result of the `outcome`.

## Coding Question (R code is provided below):

Do I need to write `outcome[i] = sample(x = c(1, 2), size = 1)` 16 times for each player and then construct something like:

```
outcome1 = sample(x = c(1, 2), size = 1)
outcome2 = sample(x = c(1, 2), size = 1)
#.
#.
#.
```

and then change the `x` of that player based on his `outcome`:

```
if(outcome1 == 1) {  points(x - .1, y, cex = 4.5, lwd = 3, pch = 21, bg = 0)  
  } else { points(x + .1, y, cex = 4.5, lwd = 3, pch = 21, bg = 0)  }
```

Or there is a better way?

[image]

[image]

## Here is my R code:

```
plot(1, ty = "n", ann = F, cex = 3)

par = par('usr')
rect(par[1], par[3], par[2], par[4], col = 'darkseagreen1' )

points( 1, 1, cex = 5, pch =20, col = 0)
points( 1, 1, cex = 33, lwd = 5, col = 0)
abline(v = 1, lwd = 10, col = 0)

rect(.6, .6, 1.4, 1.4, lwd = 5, border = 0)
rect(0, .85, .65, 1.15, lwd = 5, col = 'darkseagreen1', border = 0)
rect(1.35, .85, 1.45, 1.15, lwd = 5, col = 'darkseagreen1', border = 0)
box()

x = rep(1, 14); y = seq(.6, 1.4, len = 14)
points(x, y, cex = 4.5, lwd = 3, pch = 21, bg = 0)
text(x, y, 1:14, font = 2)
```

Comment: How about `xoffsetVec <- sample(c(-0.1, 0.1), 14, replace = TRUE)` and then updating `x <- x + xoffsetVec` in each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first sample all the moves for each player and store that in a matrix (rows are the players, columns are the time steps):

```
nSteps <- 16
nPlayers <- 14

## Sample movement of players:
xStepsMx <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1)*0.1, nPlayers*nSteps, replace = TRUE),
        nrow = nPlayers, ncol = nSteps)
```

You can then evaluate the position of each player at each time step:

```
## Position of players:
xPosMx <- t(sapply(1:nrow(xStepsMx), function(ii) cumsum(xStepsMx[ii,]))) + x
```

For each time step `timeStep` in 1,2,...,16 you can then e.g. plot your players' position using

```
timeStep <- 5    
points(xPosMx[,timeStep], y, cex = 4.5, lwd = 3, pch = 21, bg = "white")
text(xPosMx[,timeStep], y, 1:14, font = 2)
```

Comment: @parvinkarimi if you just want the x-position of each player at each time step then, yes, you can increase the value of `nPlayers`. You will just have to adapt the initial vector `x` as well (i.e., `x <- rep(1, nPlayers)`)

Comment: The matrix `xPosMx` stores the positions of all players for each time step. So if you want to know the position of player `i` at time `t`, you find that as `xPosMx[i,t]`. The initial position (that would be at time step 0) is not stored in the matrix, but given in your vector `x`. Time step `t = 1` (the first column in `xPosMx`) is the time after the first movement of your players.

Comment: Here, `nSteps` is the total number of times each player tosses the coin. After each coin toss he moves either left or right according to the result of the toss. If you just want to know where each player landed after 16 tosses you can find that in the last column of `xPosMx`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143341/discussion-between-ikop-and-parvin-karimi).

Comment: Dear iKop, could you possibly let me know when you get a chance?